# How to properly Handle a state by user typing and timeout Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have simple interactive app, and i want to render the CardList component, base on user search. the problem is i want to setTimeOut for the user search, and execute the function after 2000ms from when the user stoped typing.

here is the code, as you can see I managed to get it done, but its hacky and not really useful,im positive there is a better way to do this.
what I'm doing right now is to always change this.state.robots arrry, acording to the user input. notice the searchBox component has an input field

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            robots: robots,
            searchField: ''
        }
    }

    onSearchange = (event) =>{ 
        let timeOut = null;
        this.setState({searchField: event.target.value,robots:robots});

        event.target.onkeyup = (e) =>{
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            timeOut = setTimeout(()=> {
                const  filterRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
                    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase());
                })
                this.setState({robots: filterRobots});
            },2000);

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "tc">
                <h1>RoboFriend</h1>
                <SearchBox searchChange = {this.onSearchange}/> 
                <CardList robots = {this.state.robots} />
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to send fillterRobots array dynamically to the CardList component so i can render the results properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like lodash's [debounce()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce). You don't just want a delay, you also want to cancel the previous delayed function execution if you receive a new event before the current delayed function has executed.

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.delayedCallback = _.debounce(this.handleChange, 1000);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  onChange(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.delayedCallback(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```